# Intellij asks for Postgresql dependency when it is there

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, intellij-idea

My Ide Intellij is complaining in a class with the following message `"Cannot resolve symbol PSQLException"`. I click on the red code and he shows this popup:

[image]

Now, it is strange that asks for that specific dependency. I actually have the following in my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>
```

and even if I replace it with the version requested, the class `PSQLException` is not recognized.

Suggestion?

Comment: try the following - right click on the project in the project explorer and do Maven - Reimport (in my case it's second to last item)

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip. Unfortunately reimporting all the maven dependencies doesn't help

Comment: that's strange. what happens if you compile it with maven from comand line with `mvn package`?  (you might want to do `mvn clean` first)

Comment: I guess the class is available in every version of posgressql but the version of the dependency IntelliJ wants to add (9.4.1207) seems to differ from yours (9.4-1206-jdbc42).

Comment: @Vladimir `mvn clean package` didn't help. :(

Comment: @mat_boy does it compile with maven? it can point to where problem is - in your pom.xml or the classpath Idea uses

Comment: @Vladimir Yes!!! It compiles with maven via command line. I didn't try before, only via IntelliJ

Comment: @Vladimir issue fixed. Read the answer and start to laugh loudly!

Comment: @mat_boy I was sure such issue should have been fixed by reimport. looks like a bug in Idea to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was due to **IntelliJ 15** In the `.iml` file I had the following entry

```
<orderEntry type="library" scope="RUNTIME" name="Maven:
       org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42" level="project" />
```

because the dependency in the pom was having the scope set to runtime. When I had to import the exception, I removed the runtime scope, but that wasn't removed by intellij from the `.iml` file.

Actually, IntelliJ has very often such an annoying behavior. I don't know why I didn't recognized this early.